# How to increase ListViewItem Opacity on Mouseover?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, mouseevent, opacity

I am dimming the `Opacity` on the custom control items in a `ListView` and would like to have them set back to full opacity `OnMouseOver`. I can dim them `OnMouseOver`, but I can not increase the `Opacity`. I am guessing it has something to do with the `ListView` ControlTemplate. Any help is appreciated it is getting very frustrating:

```
<ListView Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".9"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <notify:NotificationInfo/>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is useful:

```
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem>Johan</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Ray</ListViewItem>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".9"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".2"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Did not feel super nice.